# Help identifying a programming/scripting language

Tags: programming-languages

Can anyone identify this programming/scripting language off of a few examples of the syntax?  It appears each file (function?) starts with:

```
sym int all
terminal read off
hc read off
eq
```

And also contains such syntax as: (note IDENT is used for what appears to be an identifier)

```
IDENT1=(IDENT2/123.4)*IDENT3
```

```
INPUT TABLE
IDENT / 0. 0. 0. 0.
0. 0.
0. 0.
0. 0.
ENDIN
```

```
in tb '/unix/path' ident
```

And it appears each numeric literal in the source must end with a ., so valid numbers appear to be

```
123.
123.456
.456
```

There does not appear to be any form of epilogue to the samples I am looking at, the code just stops with a final assignment (or what I'm assuming is an assignment)

Comment: What context did you find it in?

Comment: Unfortunately I can't answer that due to NDAs.

Comment: The top result on Google for both "sym int all" and "terminal read off" (which you say occur in every file, so can probably be assumed to be settings similar to VB's "Option Explicit") is this question. Either this language has somehow gone undocumented to an incredible degree, or it's proprietary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have determined that this is in fact proprietary.

Answer (score 2):

Since "sym int all" fails to google anything relevant, and since you've signed an NDA, I'm going to place my money on "proprietary."

I looked further into CSound (which I've messed with just a bit in CSoundVST), and while there is an E`NDIN`, I never see it close `INPUT`. It's used to close `instr` blocks.

Answer (score 0):

It might be [Csound](http://www.csounds.com/tootsother/vercoetut/Vercoe.html) / [Algoscore](http://download.gna.org/algoscore/Help/algoscore-manual.pdf)

Comment: CSound does have tables and an ENDIN opcode, so I think you win the prize.

Comment: Isn't algoscore just a gui on top of csound?

Comment: From looking at the links provided, I do not believe the language is CSound syntax.

Comment: @nosredna - yes, algoscore is just a gui on top of csound